# Adding a dropdown box with hover in CSS

Tags: html, css, grid, hover

I'm trying to practice on Html-CSS. I used some grids and I created a simple design, I try to add a hover under the `MUSIC` Button, like a dropdown in the navigation bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="linkin park web page.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="logo.jpeg" alt="logo" height="50px" width="50px">
        </div>
            <div class="topwriting">LINKIN PARK </div> 
            <div class="list">
        
                        
                <div><a class="main" href="Home.html">HOME</a></div>
                <div><a  class="main" href="Home.html" >ABOUT</a></div>               
                <div class="button"><button class="buttonview">MUSIC</button>
                        <div class="dropdown_content">
                            <a id= altbutton1> albums</a>
                            <a id= altbutton2> singles</a>
                            <a id= altbutton3> others</a>
                        </div>
                   
                    
               </div>
                <div><a class="main" href="Home.html">VIDEOS</a></div>
                <div><a  class="main" href="Home.html">CONTACT</a></div>
            
        </div>
        <div>
            <!--<img id="p1" src="photos/f1.jpeg" alt="photo 1"  height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p2" src="photos/f2.jpg" alt="photo 2" height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p3" src="photos/f3.jpg" alt="photo 3" height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p4" src="photos/f5.jpg" alt="photo 4" height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p5" src="photos/f6.jpg" alt="photo 5" height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p6" src="photos/f7.jpg" alt="photo 6" height="220px" width="320px" >
            -->
        </div>
        <div><p id="lastquote">  “The hardest part of ending is starting again.” </p></div>
    </div>
</body>



</html>
```

```
body{
    background-image: url("album covers.jpg");
    color: white;
    
       
}
#page{
    max-width: 900px;
    min-width: 999px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr, 2fr,  15fr, 2fr; 
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif ;

}
.list{
    border: white solid 1px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);
    text-align: center; 
    overflow: hidden;   
}
.list>div>a , .button{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    
}

.topwriting{
font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif ;
color: white;
font-size: 50px;
letter-spacing: 0.0001em;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 0em;
border-width: 2px;
border: white;
border-style: none;
margin-top: 0em;

}
#logo{
    
    border-width: 2px;
    border: white;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    width: 5% ;
    margin: 10px auto 25px auto ;
}
.button{
    
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.buttonview{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
}
.buttonview:hover{
    background-color: cadetblue;
}
.dropdown_content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.button>div>a{
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    float: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
}

.button>div>div>a:hover{
background-color: red;
}
.button:hover .dropdown_content{
    display: block;
}
#lastquote{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0,05px;
}
```

`dropdown-content` must show up under the `MUSIC` button but nothing show up or all `dropdown-content` stay right under there. How can I add a dropdown box under the  `MUSIC` with hover ? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove position:absolute from dropdown-content

```css
body{
    background-image: url("album covers.jpg");
    color: white;
    
       
}
#page{
    max-width: 900px;
    min-width: 999px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr, 2fr,  15fr, 2fr; 
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif ;

}
.list{
    border: white solid 1px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);
    text-align: center; 
    overflow: hidden;   
}
.list>div>a , .button{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    
}

.topwriting{
font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif ;
color: white;
font-size: 50px;
letter-spacing: 0.0001em;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 0em;
border-width: 2px;
border: white;
border-style: none;
margin-top: 0em;

}
#logo{
    
    border-width: 2px;
    border: white;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    width: 5% ;
    margin: 10px auto 25px auto ;
}
.button{
    
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.buttonview{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
}
.buttonview:hover{
    background-color: cadetblue;
}
.dropdown_content{
    display: none;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    background-color: cadetblue;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.button>div>a{
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    float: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
}

.button>div>div>a:hover{
background-color: red;
}
.button:hover  .dropdown_content{
    display: block;
}
#lastquote{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0,05px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="linkin park web page.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="logo.jpeg" alt="logo" height="50px" width="50px">
        </div>
            <div class="topwriting">LINKIN PARK </div> 
            <div class="list">
        
                        
                <div><a class="main" href="Home.html">HOME</a></div>
                <div><a  class="main" href="Home.html" >ABOUT</a></div>               
                <div class="button"><button class="buttonview">MUSIC</button>
                        <div class="dropdown_content">
                            <a id= altbutton1> albums</a>
                            <a id= altbutton2> singles</a>
                            <a id= altbutton3> others</a>
                        </div>
                   
                    
               </div>
                <div><a class="main" href="Home.html">VIDEOS</a></div>
                <div><a  class="main" href="Home.html">CONTACT</a></div>
            
        </div>
        <div>
            <!--<img id="p1" src="photos/f1.jpeg" alt="photo 1"  height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p2" src="photos/f2.jpg" alt="photo 2" height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p3" src="photos/f3.jpg" alt="photo 3" height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p4" src="photos/f5.jpg" alt="photo 4" height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p5" src="photos/f6.jpg" alt="photo 5" height="220px" width="320px">
            <img id="p6" src="photos/f7.jpg" alt="photo 6" height="220px" width="320px" >
            -->
        </div>
        <div><p id="lastquote">  “The hardest part of ending is starting again.” </p></div>
    </div>
</body>



</html>
```

or you can try w3's version:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Dropdown Button</h2>
  <p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown content.</p>
  <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
<button class="w3-button w3-black">Hover Over Me!</button>
<div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border">
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```